# In Rails 3's "bundle install" of local gem (frozen gem), keep getting "Source does not contain any versions of ..."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I am using a gem which is in `vendor/gems/some-api-0.1.0`, copied over from another project, and added to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'some-api', :path => '~/development/myproj/vendor/gems/some-api-0.1.0'
```

but if I do the following, it will fail with the message:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'some-api (>= 0)' in source at ~/development/myproj/vendor/gems/some-api-0.1.0.
Source does not contain any versions of 'some-api (>= 0)'
```

Searching on the net seem to suggest needing a gemspec?  So I need to write up a `.gemspec` some where, is that true?  Can someone shred light of how it is done in this situation?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but perhaps it's the ~ reference to your home directory? Try an absolute path instead (eg. /Users/username/development/myproj..."

Comment: Is this a gem you created or public gem?

Answer (score 26):

There are many other similar posts on stackoverflow, but just in case someone stumble across this post:

For some reason, when you are trying to use a gem from local source, you need to specify exactly which version of the gem you are using, e.g.

```
gem 'some-api', '0.2.0', :path => '~/development/myproj/vendor/gems/some-api-0.1.0'
```

Comment: This answer wasn't working for me. But then I re-cloned my local gem and it worked again. So maybe me gem directory was corrupt in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Just claiming there is a gem in the :path doesn't mean there actually is a gem there. Gems have gemspec files describing the name of the gem, what files belong to the gem, and various other information.

If `some-api-0.1.0` should contain a file named `some-api.gemspec` in the :path directory, and it should contain information about the gem that bundler could use to require the gem out of the :path.